# Function template with the same parameters

Tags: c++, templates

What the best way to make a function template with the same parameters?

For example:

```
template<class T>
int foo(const T &item) {
    // ...
    return item;
};

template<class T, class NotUsed>
char foo(const T &item) {
    // ...
    return item;
};

int main()
{

    std::cout << foo(1)   << std::endl; // 1
    std::cout << foo('1') << std::endl; // 1

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by that? Neither question nor example are clear. (Also, unrelatedly, it’s “function template”, not “template function”, although this is a common error.)

Comment: What's wrong with `template <class T> T foo(const T& item)`? Or `template <class T> const T& foo(const T& item)`?

Comment: @David Schwartz, I want specify type explicitly

Comment: Are you trying to distinguish two functions with the same name, based only on their return type?

Comment: @Chowlett, Yes, I want to define two functions with the same name and return their type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what your trying to do I would suggest making the return type a template parameter.

```
template<class T, class Return = int>
Return foo(const T &item) {
    // ...
    return item;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << foo<int, int>(1)   << std::endl; // 1
    std::cout << foo<char, char>('1') << std::endl; // 1
    return 0;
}
```